# How to resolve select box height issue in Android browser?

Tags: css

I am working on responsive page. In my page I used form its working fine in all browser but in Android phone browser select box are looking odd. Its not taking height is there any way to resolve this select box height issue.

Screenshot attached:

[image]
CSS code:

```
select {
  line-height: 32px;
  height: 38px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Same issue I am having and I cannot figure it out.

Comment: i used this plugin this will resolve my problem. http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

Comment: I am having the same issue. I don't want to have to resort to using a js script to fix it though. Did anyone else figure this out? @BrandonBearden?

Comment: No, I never figured out a solution. @Jambo

Comment: any solution yet? its been 2 years nearly.